# Downloading then installing through batch- how do I download then silently install an msi?

Tags: scripting, vbscript, batch-file, windows-installer

I know how to silently install an msi by using /qn.  I also know how to download something just by using the command start http://www.example.com/file.exe.  But how do I put these two together in a batch file?! I want to download it, then install it, all silently.

Answer (score 0):

Try start /w URL to see if it will modally wait. If not, download `wget for Windows` and use it with that start /w option:

`start /w "wget -c http://example..."`

`start /w "file /qn"`

`if not errorlevel 1 echo Success!`

There may be gotchas, but this should push you in the right direction.